# Select rows from Postgres where column matches any string in an array

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

This is basic, and I apologize if I missed the existing answer. I am trying to select rows in a db where the `userid` matches any string in an array I provide. Here are the methods I've tried:

```
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid = ANY([qFupLOnc1,bUVMBxum0,FlYYzQz31]) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid = ANY(['qFupLOnc1','b2VMBxum0','FlYYzQz31']) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid = ANY(ARRAY['qFupLOnc1','bUVMBxum0','FlYYzQz31']) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid = ANY(ARRAY[qFupLOnc1,bUVMBxum0,FlYYzQz31]) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid ANY(ARRAY[qFupLOnc1,bUVMBxum0,FlYYzQz31]) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid ANY(ARRAY['qFupLOnc1','bUVMBxum0','FlYYzQz31']) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid ANY(['qFupLOnc1','bUVMBxum0','FlYYzQz31']) LIMIT 5"
query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid ANY([qFupLIOnc1,bU2VMBxum0,FlYYzQz31]) LIMIT 5"
```

These all come back with an error. What's the proper way to do this?

I am querying the database via an R package `RPostgreSQL` like so:

```
data = dbGetQuery(con, query_string)
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "matches"? Is this an equality test or a pattern match? What are you expecting the `userid = ANY(ARRAY['qFupLOnc1', ...` version to find and what does it find?

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
 query_string = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid like '%foo%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid IN ('...', '...', '...');
```

Comment: Strangely this does not work. Perhaps I should expand the scope of my question to indicate that I am querying the db via an R package.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. What do you get if you run this query from the psql shell?

Comment: `c = any(array[x, y])` is equivalent to `c in (x, y)` so this shouldn't make any difference.